# AEM Query Builder: Need to search for specific text on all properties on all pages

Tags: aem, query-builder

I need to do a search for all nodes that contain a specific piece of text. I know I can use the LIKE operation for this, but the issue is how to search for the string when you are not specifying any properties? Basically if any property on any node on any page contains the string, I wwant to return those results?

Can anyone help?

G

Comment: IMHO, this doesn't seem to be a case for a single query, but rather a mix of Query plus code. A query to try to limit the amount of nodes to inspect, and via code iterating over all the node properties.

Comment: Thanks @ronnyfm this is how i ended up doing it. I am looping through the nodes, and for each node, looping through the properties to write them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to search for any substring inside any properties under any path using AEM Query Builder. You can use **asterisk** or * If you do not want a substring and just the full text then remove the "*" and give the search text;

```
path=/content
fulltext=*anyTextToSearch*
```

OR IN XPATH Query

```
/jcr:root/content/path/to/page//*[jcr:contains(., '(*anyTextToSearch*')]
```

OR IN SQL2

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:unstructured] AS node
WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(node, "/search/in/path")
AND CONTAINS([propertyName], "*anyTextToSearch*")
```

Comment: okay. are you looking for a substring in the properties? if yes, use the asterisk (*) as in the answer given.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Akshay Rathnavas

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try 'fulltext' search,

```
path=/content
fulltext=searchtext
```

Comment: unforunately not, I'm looking for a specific piece of text contained within the String.

Comment: it will give results , wherever your search string present, as a part of text.